# How to find the duplicate elements in a list of lists?

Tags: python

I got a list of lists and I would like to pick the duplicate elements out of this list of lists and print them. The list of lists is like below,

```
a = [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 375],  [142, 132, 143, 144], [172, 173, 174, 297],  [181, 182, 183, 339], [205, 144, 206, 207], [295, 108, 296, 297]]
```

I tried to use the following script,

```
for i in range(len(a)):
   for j in range(1, len(a)):
      for m in range(3):
         for n in range(3):
            if a[i][m] == a[j][n]:
                print a[j][n]
```

but it just print

```
4
5
6
142
132
143
172
173
174
181
182
183
205
144
206
295
108
296
```

ANY ONE WANT TO TRY AND HELP ME?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7
a = [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 375],  [142, 132, 143, 144], [172, 173, 174, 297],  [181, 182, 183, 339], [205, 144, 206, 207], [295, 108, 296, 297]]
a2 = []
for list1 in a:
  a2.extend(list1)
print a2
a2.sort()
for i, n in enumerate(a2):
  if i < len(a2)-2 and n == a2[i+1]:
    print (n)
```

i am pretty sure that there are other solutions which is more efficient and simpler. wait for other posts

Answer (score 0):

This code should work:

```
a = [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 375],  [142, 132, 143, 144], [172, 173, 174, 297],  [181, 182, 183, 339], [205, 144, 206, 207], [295, 108, 296, 297]]

master = [] #this will be a list with every individual element
for array in a: #take every sub-list
     for element in array: #do this for every element in the sub-list
         if not(element in master): #check that it is not a duplicate
             master.append(element) #add the element to your master list

for element in master:
    print(element)
```